# OptionSetValue behaving like an integer

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

I recently experienced an OptionSetValue behaving like an integer in a method of my plugin. Previously, and with all other OptionSetValues, to retrieve the integer value, I have used the pattern:

```
localIntegerVariable = (new_myEntity.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("new_myOptionSetAttribute")).Value;
```

That no longer works in the one of the methods of the plugin. If i treat it like an integer, it works.

```
localIntegerVariable = (new_myEntity.GetAttributeValue<int>("new_myOptionSetAttribute"));
```

Strangely enough, in the main section of the same plugin before I retrieve the pre image entity, I treat the same attribute as an OptionSetValue like below and it works just fine.

```
int incominglocalIntegerVariable = temp.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("new_myOptionSetAttribute") == null ? _OSV_Empty : temp.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("new_myOptionSetAttribute").Value;
```

I have verified that the definition of new_myOptionSetAttribute in the entities.cs file is an OptionSetValue. I have also verified that the definition in CRM is an OptionSet value.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: 'no longer works' means?

Comment: When it gets to this statement:
localIntegerVarialbe = new_myEntity.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("new_myOptionSetAttribute ").Value
It returns the following error. We are casting the OptionSetValue.Value (int) to an integer but seems to be complaining that we cannot cast the int as a OptionSetValue
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue'

Comment: whats the datatype you declared for localIntegerVariable ?

Answer (score 1):

Below code will throw exact error, because you are trying to assign right side `int` value to left side `OptionSetValue` variable:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue'

```
OptionSetValue localIntegerVariable;

localIntegerVariable = (new_myEntity.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("new_myOptionSetAttribute")).Value;
```

In this case `localIntegerVariable` should be `int`, because `.Value` will be giving you `int` datatype result.

To maintain same datatype, either change it to

```
int localIntegerVariable;

localIntegerVariable = (new_myEntity.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("new_myOptionSetAttribute")).Value;
```

or

```
OptionSetValue localIntegerVariable;

localIntegerVariable = new_myEntity.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("new_myOptionSetAttribute");
```

Last example is better, as it checks `null` check before accessing `.Value` using expression `temp.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("new_myOptionSetAttribute") == null ?`

Comment: it is already in this form:

int localIntegerVariable;  


localIntegerVariable = (new_myEntity.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("new_myOptionSetAttribute")).Value;

Comment: @THilding hows this attribute included in new_myEntity? something like new OptionSetValue(10000) ?? or PreImage or Entity from Retrieve/Retrievemultiple or target entity?